# Shopping Cart Price Rules, is such condition possible?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to setup a discount that gives:

- 20 USD off for orders over 100 USD
- 40 USD off for orders over 200 USD
- etc.

The issue:

- One category has items for $2-4 each

Is there any way to setup price rules so the cheap items from specific categories are not calculated into the amount?

The best I could think of: exclude discount if category matches X, but that just removes discount completely if user adds any cheap items.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your price rule conditions just specify that the category is not X
[image]

You'll need two rules, one for each discount. Set the priority of the higher discount rule to be lower so it runs first and then stop other rules processing.